# how to update property in nested mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to update a particular property in a nested mongo document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55af76e60b0e4b318ba822ec"),
    "make" : "MERCEDES-BENZ",
    "model" : "E-CLASS",
    "variant" : "E 250 CDI CLASSIC",
    "fuel" : "Diesel",
    "cc" : 2143,
    "seatingCapacity" : 5,
    "variant_+_fuel" : "E 250 CDI CLASSIC (Diesel)",
    "make_+_model_+_variant_+_fuel" : "MERCEDES-BENZ E-CLASS E 250 CDI CLASSIC (Diesel)",
    "dropdown_display" : "E-CLASS E 250 CDI CLASSIC (Diesel)",
    "vehicleSegment" : "HIGH END CARS",
    "abc" : {
        "variantId" : 1000815,
        "makeId" : 1000016,
        "modelId" : 1000556,
        "fuelId" : 2,
        "segmentId" : 1000002,
        "price" : 4020000
    },
    "def" : {
        "bodyType" : 1,
        "makeId" : 87,
        "modelId" : 21584,
        "fuel" : "DIESEL",
        "vehicleSegmentType" : "E2"
    },
    "isActive" : false
}
```

This is my document. If I want to add or update a value for key `"nonPreferred"` inside `"abc"`, how do I go about it?

I tried it with this query:

```
db.FourWheelerMaster.update(
    { "abc.modelId": 1000556 }, 
    {
        $Set: {
            "abc": {
                "nonPreferred": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {multi:true}
)
```

but it updates the whole `"abc"` structure, removed all key:values inside it and kept only newly inserted key values like below

```
"abc" : {
    "nonPreferred" : [
        "Mumbai",
        "Pune"
    ]
},
```

Can anyone tell me how to update only particular property inside it and not all the complete key?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the **[`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set)** operator, you need to push that array using the **[`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)** operator together with the **[`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each)** modifier to append each element of the value separately as follows:

```
db.FourWheelerMaster.update(
    { "abc.modelId": 1000556 }, 
    {
        "$push": {
            "abc.nonPreferred": {
                "$each": ["Mumbai", "Pune"]  
            }          
        }
    }, 
    { "multi": true }
)
```